# Removing User Input from the printed output in Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a program that asks for the User to input a Name(e.g. Lisbon) and any other users that falls under that has the same Country as what the User Inputs(e.g. Lisbon) will be printed out (e.g. Jade, John). Here's my JSON file:

```
{  
   "user1":{  
      "Country":[  
         "China",
         "USA",
         "Nepal"
      ],
      "Name":[  
         "Lisbon"
      ]
   },
   "user2":{  
      "Country":[  
         "Sweden",
         "China",
         "USA"
      ],
      "Name":[  
         "Jade"
      ]
   },
   "user3":{  
      "Country":[  
         "India",
         "China",
         "USA"
      ],
      "Name":[  
         "John"
      ]
   }
}
```

For example, if the User Input's Lisbon, this will be the output:

```
Lisbon
Jade
John
```

I would like to have what the User Inputs removed from the Output so the expected results would be:

```
Jade
John
```

Here's what my code looks like:

```
def Country():
    userName = raw_input("Enter user's name: ")
    with open('listOfUsers.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    def getId(name):
        for userId, v in data.items():
            if v['Name'][0] == name:
                return userId;

    id = getId(userName)
    for k, v in data.items():
    if any(x in data[id]['Country'] for x in v['Country']):
        print (v['Name'][0])
```

Comment: if any(x in data[id]['Country'] for x in v['Country']):   , if v['Name'][0] != "Lisbon": print v['Name'][0]

Comment: But thats only when the User enters specifically Lisbon, but what if the user enters Jade or John? Do I write  if v['Name'][0] != userName instead?

Comment: Side question: As of now, what the user inputs has to be exactly the same as what is in the JSON file, which in other words means case-sensitive, what do I need to change so that if the User were to type "lisbon", it would still get the same result?

Comment: You can use : str("Lisbon").ToLower()

Comment: With that , user can enter Upper or Lower case ... you get the value and call ToLower() for ensure checking always in lower casse (or invert it for Upper case) (sorry for my english)

Comment: Excuse me it's powershell or C# ToLower(), in python : str("text).lower() or str("text").upper()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me

```
def Country():
    userName = raw_input("Enter user's name: ")
    with open('listOfUsers.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    def getId(name):
        for userId, v in data.items():
            if v['Name'][0] == name:
                return userId;

    id = getId(userName)
    for k, v in data.items():
        if any(x in data[id]['Country'] for x in v['Country']):
            if v['Name'][0] != userName:
                print (v['Name'][0])
```

Comment: Side question: As of now, what the user inputs has to be exactly the same as what is in the JSON file, which in other words means case-sensitive, what do I need to change so that if the User were to type "lisbon", it would still get the same result?

Comment: You can do it this way `v['Name'][0].lower() != userName.lower()` so all the time the lower case is considered.